# react-select - setState not working

Tags: reactjs, react-select

I am new to react. I am working on a rails + react project using react select. Right now, everything works but the option to add something new if it does not already exist.

The relevant part of this is the `handleNewOption()` function

```
handleNewOption(option) {
  var self = this;
  $.ajax({
    url: '/url/',
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: { q: option.label },
    success: function(data) {
      var state = data.company;
      // state looks like {value: 1, label: "string"}
      self.setState({value: state.value, label: state.label});
    },
    error: function(xhr, status, error) {
      var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
      alert('Errors: ' + response.errors);
    }
  });
}
```

the part that is not working is the `self.setState();`. I have tried (what I have above) in addition to `self.setState(state)`, `self.setState({state})` and too many other combinations I can't even remember.

What doesn't make sense to me, is in my `handleOnChange()`, which looks like

```
handleOnChange(value) {
  this.setState({value});
}
```

is this works fine and sets the value in the form if it already exists. i have tried to pass in the exact format in `handleNewOption(option)` but it didn't work.

**EDIT:** In an effort to help, here is my full component

```
var Select = require('react-select');

var CompanySelect = React.createClass({
  getInitialState() {
    return {
      value: ''
    }
  },
  handleOnChange(value) {
    this.setState({value});
  },
  handleNewOption(option) {
    var self = this;
    $.ajax({
      url: '/url/',
      type: 'POST',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        q: option.label
      },
      success: function(data) {
        var state = data.company;
        self.setState(state);
      },
      error: function(xhr, status, error) {
        var response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        alert('Errors: ' + response);
      }
    });
  },
  getCompanies(input, callback) {
    if (input.length < 2) {
      return callback(null, {
        value: input
      });
    }

    $.ajax({
      url: '/url/search',
      type: 'GET',
      dataType: 'json',
      data: {
        q: input
      },
      success: function(data) {
        companies = data.companies.map(function(company) {
          return {
            value: company.id,
            label: company.name
          }
        });
        callback(null, {
          options: companies,
          complete: false
        });
      }
    });
  },
    render() {
      const { options, value } = this.state;
      return (
        <Select.AsyncCreatable
          multi={false}
          loadOptions={this.getCompanies}
          onChange={this.handleOnChange}
          onNewOptionClick={this.handleNewOption}
          value={value}
          promptTextCreator={(input) => {return ('Add "' + input + '"')}}
          placeholder={this.props.placeholder}
        />
      );
    }
});

module.exports = CompanySelect;
```

Does anyone see why the `setState()` in the `handleNewOption()` doesn't work? I can also post more of my react component if that would help.

Comment: Where have you defined the `state` ?

Comment: @Aaqib checkout my edit, I added my full component.

Comment: Do you bind your method? It would be easier to debug it if you provide whole component.

Comment: which version of react are you using ?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus I added my full component

Comment: @Aaqib i am using React v15.6.1

Comment: How do you know that your state is not changing? What exact info you have to confirm this?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus in my  `handleOnChange()` when it selects a match, it populates the form with the value from the select. When i use the `handleNewOption(option)` when i add a new option, the value does not change in the input. However, if I reload the page, I can see that the value i just typed is present in `handleOnChange()` and the state is correctly set. So it's correctly adding it and creating a new record on the backend, but that change is not reflected on the front end and I can only assume it's from `setState()`

Comment: Do you have some errors in console?

Comment: @MarioNikolaus no errors at all. in my ajax success function, I outputted `state` from `var state = data.company;`, and I can see the value `{value: 1264, label: "pop"}` in the exact same format that works in my `handleOnChange()`. so frustrating...have no idea why it's not working and can't find any resources, docs, or examples as to why either.

Answer (score 0):

Try to change state like this

```
success: function(data) {
  self.setState({ value: data.company });
},
```

assuming your data is in fact object with attributes value and label.

In your handleOnChange you are passing value object to state, but in your handleNewOption you are passing you are passing value string and label string to state and there you have your mismatch.

Comment: thanks for the answer! i think it's close. data is an object that holds another object i'm looking for. it looks like 
`success: function(data) {
  var state = data.company;
  self.setState({ value: state });
}`. i don't think it worked fully...but it worked better. It doesn't quite work as `handleOnChange` but it works better than before

Comment: Your answers are too vague, how is it working better than before? What does not work now?

Comment: it works better meaning i can use the enter from the react select and the value stays in the form. However, it still doesn't work exactly like `handleOnChange() ` because it doesn't close the select dropdown. sorry, i'm trying to be more specific but it's hard to describe

Comment: This question is now totally unrelated to setting state, I suggest you to read documentation on react-select and try different ways to implement behaviour you want

Comment: I think i disagree. Why would it be working in one function, but not the other?

Comment: What is response from your endpoint? Is it the same value label json? Paste the exact response you have

Comment: sorry for the delay! the response back in my `$.ajax` success function is `{company: {value: 6, label: "new option"}, status: 200}`